# what are method contracts & method specifications?

Tags: methods

I know this is for coding but I cannot find anything online that even remotely helps me understand it.

Maybe is it sort of *form*? My textbook doesn't talk about it and my lecture didn't help much with it.

Answer (score 1):

Method specification: Surely it refers to the method's **name**, **visibility**, **parameters** and its types and directions (input/output), **return value** and possible **exceptions thrown**.

Method contracts: That is the **expected behaviour**, **preconditions** and **postconditions** when that method executes.

Example: The method [Object.equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) in Java has this *specification*:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj)
```

... and this *contract*, as specified in its public documentation:

> Indicates whether some other object is "equal to" this one.
>
> The equals method implements an equivalence relation on non-null
>   object references:
>
> It is reflexive: for any non-null reference value x, x.equals(x) should return true.
>   It is symmetric: for any non-null reference values x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns
>   true.
>   It is transitive: for any non-null reference values x, y, and z, if x.equals(y) returns true and y.equals(z) returns true, then
>   x.equals(z) should return true.
>   It is consistent: for any non-null reference values x and y, multiple invocations of x.equals(y) consistently return true or
>   consistently return false, provided no information used in equals
>   comparisons on the objects is modified.
>       For any non-null reference value x, x.equals(null) should return false.
>
> The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating
>   possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null
>   reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x
>   and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).
>
> Note that it is generally necessary to override the hashCode method
>   whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general
>   contract for the hashCode method, which states that equal objects must
>   have equal hash codes.